# my mint have grasshopper eating leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, mint

I have a problem with my chocomint. I just bought it for a few weeks. But today, seem like there are some bugs are eating my plant, it's a jumper specimen. So I would like to ask you, why my mint got these bugs? because I searched for this problem on the internet and didn't find any issue like this. 
And what can I do now to protect my plant? Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that you have a leaf hopper, not a grasshopper. Can you post a photo?

Comment: Is the plant shaded?

Answer (score 1):

Grasshoppers eat almost anything. A natural solution would be to spray a garlic oil mixture on the leaves. There are some recipes online to put in a spray bottle. Some also use a dusting of flour on the leaves because it gums up the grasshoppers mouths, an added bonus and feeling of some revenge! There are some pesticides you can use if this doesn't work. Other options are to attract live predators. Birds love grasshoppers and if you add a bird feeder, the birds will come. You can also buy praying mantis egg cases and release baby praying mantis into the yard for $10-$30, depending on how many you need, and they will rid you of the grasshoppers. Lastly, get some chickens or Guniea fowl! Good luck! Sorry you have to deal with them, but most all of us have to at some time.